# Geckoboard not recognizing my Gosquared account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geckoboard

I have a Gosquared widget in my Geckoboard that is tracking one of my site.It is working perfectly fine.Now,I want to add another Gosquared widget to track another site. I entered all data correctly(site name, site ID and API key), also I have put the Gosquared tracking code on my rails application. When i try to create the widget, the connection breaks down with following error "Account does not exist.".I have no clue why its not working.Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try testing that data is being sent from the GoSquared API successfully by accessing the GoSquared API URL directly using your credentials:

http://api.gosquared.com/concurrents.json?sid={SITE_ID}&api_key={API_KEY}

Make sure you replace {SITE_ID} and {API_KEY} in that URL with your respective details.

If you receive a JSON object like {"concurrents":150,"range_max":187} then the problem may be with Geckoboard somewhere. If you get an error on the GoSquared API, contact us on support@gosquared.com or message me here!

Geoff

GoSquared

Comment: We have 4 sites under our account and that API call only works for 1 of our site ids!?!? 

http://api.gosquared.com/concurrents.json?sid=GSN-409472-L&api_key=KHRZA1J7CTIGCTAY.............returns  {"concurrents":0,"range_max":3}

...........................................................


http://api.gosquared.com/concurrents.json?sid=GSN-529439-B&api_key=KHRZA1J7CTIGCTAY ............. gives this error {"error":{"code":503,"message":"Authentication failed: you do not have permission to access this site's details"}}